# lp/lpr color printing option and lines counter

Tags: 14.04

I would like to print multiple files using  `lp` or `lpr`.The problem is that no matter how hard I have tried I can't make it print the files that I want in colour. Also I would like to add a lines counter on the printed files if this is possible of course.If `lp` or `lpr` are not capable of doing so please feel free to suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble printing in color with lp and lpr (especially with hp printers). It *may* be a driver issue, as some of the default drivers in Ubuntu have issues. Have you tried installing the manufacture's drivers? If this is an hp printer try installing the hp-lip package from the repositories.

Comment: Actually my device is connected to the network via an Edimax print server. HP-LIP is unable to detect it no matter what. "Printers" of Ubuntu though can discover it. Do you know how can I make HP-LIP find it?